# How can I do it through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, text, tags

I have such a text. In p tag I need two symbols from the end of the text to be deleted. How can I do it through javascript?

```
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: `end of the text to be deleted` what does that mean?

Comment: Show us some code mate

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `.slice`:

```
<p>text</p>
<script>
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.slice(0, -2); // returns "te"
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qaq3moof/

Answer (score 0):

try this

> html

```
<p id="txt">text+-</p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click">
```

> js

```
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
var text = $('#txt').html();
   var newStr = text.slice(0,-2);
    alert(newStr);
});
});
```

> this will do the trick for you. It uses jquery and javascript. Check out the fiddle
>   [eliminate last two symbols from a p element](https://jsfiddle.net/yg6hdb11/)